# Adding a text to the same cell

Tags: excel-formula

In order to save time and simplify my work I need to add the particle "lbs." to every cell I enter a value on.

if I type 123, I need it to automatically read 123lbs

Comment: You cannot change the cell value automatically with just a formula, you would need a VBA solution. You could however add a helper Column with the following formula: Assuming your data is in column A and you have headers, put this in B2 and drag down: `=A2&"lbs"`

Answer (score 2):

you can custom format the cells:

`#.# "lbs"`